# SQL Database automatic back up

Tags: sql, backup, lan

I have an SQL database - I need to back it up everyday (at a minimum) - preferably multiple times a day - automatically so it definitely gets done.

I'm running Windows which the SQL database is stored on.

What programs (prefer free ones) can I use to back it up - I'm completely new with SQL so if you're gonna explain something - do it in layman's terms thanks (:

It needs to get backed up to another server (on the LAN).

Comment: Maybe you should post the question at Stack Exchanges [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com) site?

Also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx) can be helpful as always if it's a Microsoft SQL Server you're using.

Comment: Ahh thanks - I was unaware of this site , I'll try there aswell (:

Comment: Are you saying **SQL** (Structured Query Langauge - just a language - no product) but you *really* mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (that's a product now)??

Comment: If you are looking for the easiest way to backup your SQL Server databases on the regular basis then use SqlBak. Here is a tutorial how to create a backup job in 2 minutes. https://sqlbak.com/blog/how-to-create-sqlbak-backup-job-in-2-minutes/ It's really simple.

Answer (score 31):

Auto Backup Database Using Maintenance Plans

Simple Step :

1. Go To SQL Server Configuration Manager  > SQL Server Services > Run SQL Server Agent (Set it to Run Automatically)
2. Go To SQL Server Management Studio, Find TAB  Management > Maintenance Plans. Right Click > Maintenance Plans Wizard.
3. Text your maintenance plans, ex: DailyBackup. Select Option button : Single Schedule for entire task.
4. Click Configure > Set Schedule  according your demands.
5. Select Maintenance tasks.  for this case, you choose Full Database backup.
6. Click Next, then define which database to backup, set backup location, and backup extension.
7. Click Next, Choose your report mode, then Finish.

Comment: Any tricks to auto-clean up old backups, say after 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

There are many such programs at the moment, you can try [EMS SQL Backup](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mssql/sqlbackup/). It is not free but it is very handy for this type of tasks and supports backups compression, encryption and upload backups to FTP, network and cloud locations.