# How to schedule a SQL Server 2016 database backup

Tags: sql-server, backup

How to schedule a SQL Server 2016 database backup? The backup will be run every week.

TIA

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616764/sql-database-automatic-back-up)

Comment: To run the backups according to your schedule you can simply use this solution https://sqlbak.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server Express, you can't use SQL Agent, so you must do it using a script (.bat or another) and schedule it with Windows Schedule task (or another program).

If you have another version, you can create a Maintenance plan for a full backup and then with SQL Agent create a Job to run it.

[See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367424/sql-backup-job-script-windows-schedule-task/41367952#41367952)

Comment: I created the following (I'll post it as a new question)

Answer (score 2):

You can create the backup script like below for you database backup:

```
BACKUP DATABASE your_database TO DISK = 'full.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE your_database TO DISK = 'diff.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL 
BACKUP LOG your_database TO DISK = 'log.bak'
```

Schedule it as per your requirement.

You can also use the Maintenance Plan Wizard; please refer to this link for reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191002.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Should I create a text file with the following statements:

Comment: BACKUP DATABASE your_database TO DISK = 'full.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE your_database TO DISK = 'diff.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL 
BACKUP LOG your_database TO DISK = 'log.bak'

Comment: Then put the file under Windows Scheduler to make it run periodically.

Comment: About the Maintenance Plan Wizard, when I create a new maintenance plan, it ask me to enable the 'Agent XPs' component using the sp_configure procedure. Could you show me the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not Express, you create a backup job, which you can do in SQL Server management Studio, and then schedule that backup job:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017#SSMS

Answer (score 0):

Check this opensource backup windows service [MFSQLBackupService](https://github.com/MohammadFneish7/MFSQLBackupService), it did a great job for me. It performs daily backup, but it is too easy to patch the weekly job.